# Format CSS output in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I'm building a small rails app that saves CSS snippets. I have a controller that allows the user to 'get' my_app.com/styles.css, which outputs plain text of all css snippets that have been entered. Is there a way I can "prettify" that css as the view is rendered? Or do I need to use some sort of javascript plugin? Or even if I could "prettify" it when it's saved in the first place. I've seen some similar server side techniques used with CSSTidy, but that's PHP only.

Edit:
Here's how I'm rendering the css view:

In my routes.rb

```
  get 'styles', to: 'styles#snippets'
```

In my controller

```
class StylesController < ApplicationController
  def snippets
    @entries = Entry.all
  end
end
```

In my view (snippets.css.erb)

```
<% @entries.each do |entry| %>
/* <%= entry.name %> 
======================================*/

<%= entry.css %>





<% end %>
```

This outputs a file with a  tag and then each CSS snippet. The whitespace is just weird. I don't want to rely on the users's input to properly render the CSS indentation on the output. I'd rather format it on the output to be indented nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can look at a couple of options

- [highlight gem](https://github.com/simplabs/highlight)
- [coderay railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/207-syntax-highlighting)
- [Pygments.rb](https://github.com/tmm1/pygments.rb)

Comment: I will take a look at them. I'm specifically wanting to format the indentation, not necessarily add a sytnax highlighting theme.

Comment: hmm. can you show how you read the file and render the contents? you can probably use `pre` to preserve the indentation and a fixed character width font

Comment: ok. your requirement where you want your app to fix the indentations is something i wasn't expecting and I can't find a gem that would help you do it. sorry.

Comment: That's ok. Sorry if I wasn't specific enough in my question. I'm kind of a rails newb. I may still try coderay, and see if I can just output the CSS text in a way that looks like plain text.

Comment: I ended up using Pygments.rb. Since your answer led me down a path to discovering Pygments, which is just an alternative for what you proposed, I added a link to it and I'm accepting this answer.